# Using node.js to get LimitOrders from 0x v4 API: once I've selected an order to fill, how do I proceed to call fillLimitOrder?

Tags: nodejs, 0x

After getting all the orders from the v4 REST API and going through them, supposing that I have found an order I would like to fill, what do I need to do from this point to successfully call fillLimitOrder on the exchange proxy? Am I missing something really obvious here? Could somebody please walk me through the next steps? I'm still a bit of a novice when it comes to Solidity and a lot of relevant docs and samples seem to be offline right now, so the more detail you can provide, the better... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example to fill the order that you want when fetched from ZRX API: https://github.com/0xProject/0x-starter-project/blob/master/src/scenarios/fill_erc20_limit_order.ts